# Django : submitting Foriegn key field with or without form object to models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

we can submit foriegnkey data to models
through ModelForm

```
class BooksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = "__all__"
```

where in templates we can add

```
{{form.author}} (author is foriegnkey field in  books model)
```

Im aware that we can submit foriegnkey data using forms  like this

but my question is.is there any way where we can submit a foriegnkey object which we have fetched using some other method (with or without form )
to a model(in my case its book)

Let me explain it in detail

lets say for instance there is a Search  bar
when users search for author,
then the function fetches list of authors (choice field) to the user
where user can select and submit

which should get populated in the books model

there isnt any proper info related to this on web
all i could see is information on how to save data with Foriegnnkey using model form

any kind of insights is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your desired outcome is - this is how I understand your issue:

If you want to create a `Book` entry while passing an `Author` instance along you could set it as follows:

```
# models.py

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

```
# views.py

def example_view(request):
   selected_author_instance = Author.objects.get(pk=1)  # example query, adjust to your needs
   
   # Create Book instance and pass author instance along
   book_instance = Book.objects.create(
                          author=selected_author_instance,
                          title='example'
                         )
   book_instance.save()

   return render(...)
```